# sudo subl, starts sublime without global menu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, sublimetext3

Recently I installed Sublime Text 3 on Ubuntu 14.04. It works fine but when I starts it by **sudo** command, the sublime starts with menu in windows and not global menu, While it starts in regular mode with global menu.

I tried to hide menu in **sudo subl** mode but that actually hides the menu, and again not shows any menu in global in Taskbar.

What's the wrong?

Comment: Don't run a GUI application with `sudo` in the first place.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for your answer. Sorry I'm beginner in Linux, So how can I run GUI applications which able to edit secured files?

Comment: A common  workaround is to edit a temporary file. Some editors also have  facilities for editing privileged files without running the entire application in privileged mode. (I only ever used Emacs and `visudo` and naïvely think I don't need to know about others.)

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea in general to run graphical application with sudo as pointed out by *tripleee*. You can use `gksudo` or `sudo -H subl` to run sublime with elevated privileges.

But I think to fix the global menu issue you may want to reinstall both gtk modules.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-gtk2-module
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-gtk3-module
```